# making parent process wait till child has called exec

Tags: linux, fork

In linux, after calling fork(), my child process is going to call exec soon. Is there a way for the parent process to wait() and not do anything till the child has exec'ed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vfork()` instead of `fork()`. That causes the parent to be suspended until the child either exits or calls one of the `execve()` family of functions.

Answer (score 4):

There is no (API) way for the parent to know that the child is performing an exec().

But there is a nice pipe-trick: have the child inherit a filedescriptor (for a pipe) and (before the fork() ) set the close-on-exec flag for the pipe. The parent will be notified by an EOF on the pipe when it is closed by the exec().

Please note that this does not need any collaboration from the child.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) using the process ID returned from the [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) call that is returned to the parent.

**EDIT**

Or if you mean that you want to know that the child is about to call exec use [pause](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause) in the parent. Get the child to call [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) with a suitable signal to the parent (whose process ID can be obtained from [getppid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getppid)). USR1 signal might be useful to use. Do this just before the exec.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how waitpid() relates to OP's requirement to detect when the child calls exec*().

Comment: As noted by IBY, I cannot find any status to use with waitpid that indicates that the child has exec'ed

Comment: I took "has exec`ed" to mean that the child has execute a program to completion.